# Nest js - Cors error about 'access-control-allow-origin'

Tags: reactjs, cookies, cors, nest

I'm currently developing a reservation system and the authentication I use is JWT and saving it in my cookie. However, I got a error about cors like this.

```
guestinfo:1 Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:4000/auth/login' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'
```

[image: error 1]

### Nest JS code

```
  app.use(function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', [
      'https://127.0.0.1:3000/',
      'https://localhost:3000/',
      'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
      'https://localhost:3000',
    ]);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    );
    next();
  });

  app.enableCors({
    origin: [
      'https://127.0.0.1:3000/',
      'https://localhost:3000/',
      'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
      'https://localhost:3000',
    ],
    credentials: true,
    // methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    // allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    // maxAge: 86400,
  });
  await app.listen(4000);
```

### React Code

```
  const login = async () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      credentials: 'include',
      withCredentials: true,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      path: '/',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: "ID",
        password: "PASSWORD"
      })
    };
```

I'd tried credentials, https, httpOnly, Secure, sameSite, expires options. But these didn't working and still get in.
In my opinion, this problem is 'access-control-allow-origin'. But it isn't changed.

How can I solve this error? Please help me.

Comment: Try deleting credentials include and making with credentials false

Comment: Also show the response

Comment: Try changing from https to http

Comment: @devin Thank you for replying! I delete credentials include, change credentials false and https to http. But it's not store the cookie..

Comment: I think you only need to change https to http change the credential stuff back.

Comment: also I am unable to see if your login function is calling this middleware

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `res.header`, you can set cors configuration just by using  `app.enableCors`. I suspect that those two configurations are conflicting, make use of `app.enableCors`

Make sure you provide the `origin` and the `methods` allowed.

This should work:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors({
    origin: [
      'https://127.0.0.1:3000/',
      'https://localhost:3000/',
      'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
      'https://localhost:3000',
    ],
    methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(4000);
}
bootstrap();
```